# Iterator doesn't work with DataLoader on GPU

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I'm using PyTorch on Google Colab, I'm getting this error when Using GPU,

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-41cdbc758ecd> in <module>()
----> 1 dataiter= iter(trainloader)

TypeError: '_SingleProcessDataLoaderIter' object is not callable
```

but wen using normal CPU there is no Error.

My code:

```
%matplotlib inline
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'retina'

import torch
import numpy as np
from torchvision import datasets, transforms

from collections import  OrderedDict

from torch import nn
from torch import  optim
import torch.nn.functional as F
import helper


transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),
     transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])

trainset= datasets.MNIST("MINIST_data/", download= True, train=True, transform=transform)
trainloader= torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size= 64, shuffle=True)
dataiter= iter(trainloader)
```

Using `enumerate` instead of `iter` works with GPU but I don't know why, can someone explain the error to me and why it is happening !?

Comment: your code is working with me on colab

Comment: @Mughees Runs on the GPU?!

Comment: yes, it works with gpu

Comment: Maybe the torch version is the reason ??

Comment: you are installing yourself? as torch at colab is same 1.6

Comment: @AbdEl-RahmanAkram Have you figured out the reason. For me the working code which used iter(dataloader) started throwing error next day. GPU not the reason ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to use iter. `trainloader` is already iterable. The loop should be done like this `for data in trainloader:` or `for index, data in enumerate(trainloader):`

Comment: for those reading it – older versions of PyTorch required iter() on trainloader.

For google –I got here after getting 
> AttributeError: '_SingleProcessDataLoaderIter' object has no attribute 'next'

Answer (score 6):

If you need to load just one step, `next()`  does not work with a `DataLoader` like this:`next(data_loader)` directly, giving the error: `TypeError: 'DataLoader' object is not an iterator`.

To go one step:`next(enumerate(data_loader))` works.